# How do I replace all spaces but not newlines bash?

Tags: bash

How can I remove all whitespaces, but not newlines in bash? I'm trying to create a file with the following command:

```
curl -s https://gateblogs.com/sitemap.xml | grep loc | sed 's/<loc>//g' | sed 's/<\/loc>//g'
```

, the problem is that I need to remove all whitespaces, while keeping all the newlines.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `grep` and `sed` rather than an XML-aware tool? `xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//loc' -v . -n` or such would work even if your input is reformatted to have no newlines at all, or in other respects that would confuse your current approach.

Comment: (well -- there's a non-default XML namespace, so that would actually be: `xmlstarlet sel -N sm="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" -t -m '//sm:loc' -v . -n <sitemap.xml`)

Comment: I didn’t know xml tools existed for bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one in awk:

```
$ curl ... | awk '/<loc>/{gsub(/<\/?loc>|[[:space:]]/,"");print}'
```

Explained:

```
awk '
/<loc>/ {                            # process only lines with loc tag on it
    gsub(/<\/?loc>|[[:space:]]/,"")  # remove tags and whitespace
    print                            # print
}'
```

*Standard disclaimer for processing xml with xml clueless tools*

**Edit**:

I got curious regarding the comments for [@rth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45498120/4162356) and run some speed tests. I wrote a million records of line `<loc>https://stackoverflow.com</loc>` with:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=1000000;i++)print " <loc>https://stackoverflow.com</loc>"}' > tehtest
```

and proceeded to test. Best of three presented:

```
$ time cat tehtest |sed 's/<loc>//g' | sed "s/[[:blank:]]*//g" | sed 's/<\/loc>//g' > out1

real    0m39.973s
user    0m42.288s
sys     0m0.600s

$ time cat tehtest | sed -e 's/<loc>//g' -e 's/[[:blank:]]*//g' -e 's/<\/loc>//g' > out2

real    0m40.366s
user    0m40.220s
sys     0m0.212s

$ time cat tehtest|awk '{gsub(/<\/?loc>|[[:space:]]/,"");print}' > out3

real    0m4.053s
user    0m3.988s
sys     0m0.188s
```

Comment: Thank you for the test. Please take a look at my answer where I've provided an example of fast pipeline solution.

Answer (score 2):

Or, with [html-xml-utils](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/)

```
curl -s <http_address> | hxnormalize -x | hxselect -c "loc"
```

where `hxnormalize` pretty-prints the html file and `hxselect` outputs  the given elements. The `-c` option outputs the contents of the matched element. Without `−c`, the start and end tag of the matched element are printed as well.

Use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't an elegant solution, but you can use sed to remove any space or tabs for any place. Like this

```
curl -s https://gateblogs.com/sitemap.xml | grep loc | sed 's/<loc>//g' | sed "s/[[:blank:]]*//g" | sed 's/<\/loc>//g'
```

**EDIT**

I appreciate [@JamesBrown test in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45499021/1887559). To show that pipeline may be faster than multiple conditions in single core application, I designed simple example. *Note: I designed this example very specific just to show a case when using pipelines has a benefit for performance. This example slightly related to the main questions*. I may get a lot of -1 but it may be useful to show an example when the pipeline solution is faster.

Here python script for a test file generation:

```
with open("testpipeline","w") as fd:
    for l in xrange(10000):
        for ins in xrange(200):
            fd.write(" <loc> ")
            for k in xrange(30):
                fd.write(" https://stackoverflow.com")
            fd.write(" </loc>                              ")
        fd.write("\n")
```

The test indicates better performance with the pipelines than on single core.

```
$python testpipline.py 
$time cat testpipeline |sed 's/<\/loc>.*<loc>//g' | sed "s/[[:blank:]]*//g" > /dev/null

real    0m27.470s
user    0m38.628s
sys     0m1.232s
$ time cat testpipeline |sed -e 's/<\/loc>.*<loc>//g' -e "s/[[:blank:]]*//g" > /dev/null

real    0m38.382s
user    0m37.716s
sys     0m1.132s
```

Finally, if we remove cat, it becomes about 30% faster than single core

```
$ time sed 's/<\/loc>.*<loc>//g' testpipeline | sed "s/[[:blank:]]*//g" > /dev/null

real    0m26.611s
user    0m38.468s
sys     0m0.268s
```

I hope it will help and someone can develop an intuition, which will help to decide what is the most optimal solution in some particular case.

Comment: Why call three separate instances of `sed` rather than passing one instance three expressions? `sed -e 's/<loc>//g' -e 's/[[:blank:]]*//g' -e 's/<\/loc>//g'`. You don't even need the `grep` if you ask `sed` to do that work as well (which it's perfectly capable of).

Comment: ...that said, this approach depends on the folks who maintain the sitemap deciding that they care more about their XML being human-readable than about it being compact -- if they decide to take out both the spaces *and* the newlines in a future version (which they're perfectly able to do without impacting how a browser or XML parser interprets the file), then this approach as a whole is hosed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I'm not sure, it is a good idea. Passing one instance three expressions will be one process, which will do quite a lot of work on one core. Making pipeline is distributed this filtering over cores. If filter more complicated than that or you need filter more than that, the pipeline will be faster. At list in my hands ;)

Comment: The overhead you pay to start up three separate processes is going to **far** outweigh the benefit you get from spreading out a 300-line file. And even if it didn't, you'll have more overhead from reading from and writing to FIFOs.

Comment: Keep in mind that each read or write is at minimum two context switches between userland and kernelspace; those don't come free.

Comment: ...*and* each context switch means that the relevant kernel code needs to be in the CPU's cache. It's vastly more overhead than staying inside one userland process.

Comment: XeX, you may be right about kernelspace, but filtering long (100G) and single line files are much faster in pipeline than on single process.

Comment: I'm not accepting that as true without the context of a specific filter for which you assert it entered into evidence; without that context, the assertion is effectively untestable.

Comment: Well, a batch of numbers from an experiment, where you need to find specific patterns and subpatterns inside the patterns.  On 4 cores Intel (really don't remember which one exactly) pipeline works 2-3 time faster than processing on a single core. Look at my icon that is 3 neurons talk to each other.

Comment: Got curious about your discussion on the matter and did a little test [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45499021/4162356).

Comment: ...so my takeaway there is that `sed` -- specifically -- is slow enough that the benefits of parallelization overwhelms its costs.

Comment: I was a bit amazed myself. I took the regex from my awk solution and applied it to `sed` and the time doubled.

Comment: @JamesBrown I can believe that. But the point is still the same. In a complicated filtering (no matter sed or awk) pipeline through several awk/sed commands may be (not always) much effective than single awk/sed with a bunch of conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to use non-XML-aware tools to parse XML files. With XMLStarlet:

```
curl -s https://gateblogs.com/sitemap.xml | \
  xmlstarlet sel -N sm="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" -t -m '//sm:loc' -v . -n <sitemap.xml
```

...or, if you need to run this somewhere that isn't installed, you can use an equivalent XSLT template. If you have the following content (which XMLStarlet will programmatically generate when the `-C` argument is passed to `xmlstarlet sel` with the query one wants to generate a template for) named `extract-locs.xslt`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:sm="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="exslt">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//sm:loc">
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="."/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="value-of-template">
    <xsl:param name="select"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$select"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($select)[position()&gt;1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...then you can get the exact same output from:

```
xsltproc extract-sitemap.xslt - <sitemap.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `| column -t`

so, that would be

```
curl -s https://gateblogs.com/sitemap.xml | grep loc | sed 's/<loc>//g' | sed 's/<\/loc>//g' | column -t
```